# Python script for changing windows path to unix path

Tags: python, linux, bash, escaping

I want a script where I can paste a windows path as argument, and then the script converts the path to unix path and open the path using nautilus.

I want to be able to use the script as follows:

```
mypythonscript.py \\thewindowspath\subpath\
```

The script currently looks like this:

```
import sys, os

path = "nautilus smb:"+sys.argv[1]

path = path.replace("\\","/")

os.system(path)
```

I almost works :)
The problem is that I have to add ' around the argument... like this:

```
mypythonscript.py '\\thewindowspath\subpath\'
```

Anyone who knows how I can write a script that allows that argument is without ' , ... i.e. like this:

```
mypythonscript.py \\thewindowspath\subpath\
```

EDIT: I think I have to add that the problem is that without ' the \ in the argument is treated as escape character. The solution does not necessarily have to be a python script but I want (in Linux) to be able to just paste a windows path as argument to a script.

Comment: What is the source for the strings? You could create a simple GUI to avoid escaping and/or investigate drag-n-drop on a script icon/applet solution.

Comment: The strings with the windows path I receive in emails. Maybe I have to create a GUI app for this as you suggest... But I just think that this should be a quite common problem?!?

Comment: or just read the directly from clipboard: `xclip -o`

Comment: Since I see you have multiple language tags, if you're just looking for a solution that works, there's [winepath](http://wiki.winehq.org/winepath). I expect it's probably more robust than any script you can slap together in a few minutes, if you happen to have wine available.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're using a really early version of Windows: "/blah/whatever/" just works for your OP.

Comment: I think the OP means that it should work for pasted paths, I guess from the file explorer.

Comment: The windows path is in the format using \ (received in various emails)
I just want to be able to copy and paste as argument to the script.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#! python3
#! python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""win2ubu.py changes WINFILEPATH Printing UBUNTU_FILEPATH
Author: Joe Dorocak aka Joe Codeswell (JoeCodeswell.com)
Usage:   win2ubu.py WINFILEPATH
Example: win2ubu.py "C:\\1d\ProgressiveWebAppPjs\\Polymer2.0Pjs\\PolymerRedux\\zetc\\polymer-redux-polymer-2"
    prints /mnt/c/1d/ProgressiveWebAppPjs/Polymer2.0Pjs/PolymerRedux/zetc/polymer-redux-polymer-2
        N.B. spaceless path needs quotes in BASH on Windows   but NOT in Windows DOS prompt!
"""
import sys,os

def winPath2ubuPath(winpath):
    # d,p = os.path.splitdrive(winpath) # NG only works on windows!
    d,p = winpath.split(':')
    ubupath = '/mnt/'+d.lower()+p.replace('\\','/')   
    print (ubupath)
    return ubupath

NUM_ARGS = 1
def main():
    args = sys.argv[1:]
    if len(args) != NUM_ARGS or "-h" in args or "--help" in args:
        print (__doc__)
        sys.exit(2)
    winPath2ubuPath(args[0])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid dealing with escapes in the shell you could work with the clipboard directly:

```
import os
try:
    from Tkinter import Tk
except ImportError:
    from tkinter import Tk # py3k

# get path from clipboard
path = Tk().selection_get(selection='CLIPBOARD')

# convert path and open it
cmd = 'nautilus'
os.execlp(cmd, cmd, 'smb:' + path.replace('\\', '/'))
```

`ntpath`, `urlparse`, `os.path` modules might help to handle the paths more robustly.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I had something like this a while ago, I made a bash script to automatically download links I copy into clipboard, here it is edited to use your program (you first need to install `xclip` if you don't already have it):

```
#!/bin/bash

old=""
new=""

old="$(xclip -out -selection c)"

while true 
do

   new="$(xclip -out -selection c)"

   if [ "$new" != "$old" ]
   then
      old="$new"

      echo Found: $new
      mypythonscript.py $new

   fi
   sleep 1
done

exit 0
```

Now whenever you copy something new into the clipboard, your Python script will be executed with an argument of whatever is in your clipboard.

Comment: Thank you!!
This was even better than I ever could have dream of! :)

Answer (score -1):

may want to try

```
my_argv_path = " ".join(sys.argv[1:])
```

as the only reason it would split the path into separate args is spaces in pasted path

(eg: `C:\Program Files`     would end up as two args   `["c:\Program","Files"]`)

Comment: dunno why you downvoted me ... downvote without explanation isnt very helpful